# Using the YouTube API I'm getting "invalid filter parameter" error. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

Here is a link to a direct copy of the spreadsheet: [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fbgCk-kakZlhv40ghnrzhWPD7c2BMQgZiM4ASm_TyBs/edit?usp=sharing)

The script that has stopped working is called "Live", 24 Hour still works as intended. When running the script (as it should On Open) it no longer updates, instead the following error message appears;

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request specifies an invalid filter parameter. (line 41, file "Live")

I haven't touched or changed anything about the script since it was created, and I have been using the same script for several months on each spreadsheet I have (youll notice the spreadsheet is named after the month its in use)

Comment: to add, the exact same script in any other of my sheets is still working

Comment: You are hitting the max results per request *hidden* quota @InfoKuris

Answer (score 5):

### You are exceeding the `maxResults` filter's maximum of 50 Ids.

You are making a request to `YouTube.Videos.List` and using the `id` filter.

- The `maxResults` *Optional parameter* states a max value of 50, even though not in conjuction with the `id` filter.
- However, when testing your script with more than 50 Ids, I too got the error.

#### Solution:

- Keep the max `Ids` per request at 50. (Make multiple requests if needed.)

---

#### Docs:

[Youtube API Videos.List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters) documentation.

Comment: thanks for the help, how do I make a new request? do i just need a new script on a new sheet?

Comment: You could make an array of Ids list, with each element being 50 Ids max, and for-loop your `getStats` function with the list items. @InfoKuris.